# How to store dynamically loaded files as class member - pointer, non-pointer member, in vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, member, unique-ptr

EDIT: Some changes, because I think there are some misunderstandings.

Lets say I have a `MainWindow` class as a part of my programs gui. With a `FileChooser` dialog I want to load a image file into my program. At the moment I get the filename of the choosen file, construct an `Image` object which hides the loading logic and want to store it as a part of my `MainWindow` class. My question is, how would you store the object. I know that there is only one loaded image at the same time, so the use of container formats like `std::vector` seems not very useful for me.

My thoughs were:

-to use a non-pointer member. But thats difficult, because I'm not able to construct the `Image` object at the construct time of the `MainWindow` class.

-to use `unique_ptr`, because I would say it's ok when the `MainWindow` takes ownership, but I'm not sure if thats very useful when I have to pass the pointer around (to objects\widgets that can show some specific contens of the datasets).

-to use `shared_ptr` in this case to allow child widgets to store their own pointer to the `Image` object

I know it's a "noobish" question, but I have no good ideas at the moment.

Comment: If you need to share the dataset reference, then you have to use `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` helps only when there is a single reference to the object. I didn't get the part with the vector, but you can have a `vector<shared_ptr<dataset>>` too.

Comment: A data set should not be a member of a GUI object. Your GUI should be separate from the code that actually does the work.

Comment: Most classes have a default constructor, and you can usually figure out a way to know if it's been initialized or not. Is that not the case for your `Image` class?

Answer (score 1):

The canonical approach to store a file would be a `std::vector<uint8_t>`.

If your program operates on a single dataset at a time that should be sufficient.

After construction of your `MainWindow` class the vector would just be empty until you decide to load a file (I think that's what you wanted to express by saying *a normal member seems difficult to me*).

If it's possible to load multiple datasets into your program you could go with a `std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>>`.

Since `std::vector` already gives you most of the functionality you will need (like storing the size of your buffer, simple resizing, etc) I wouldn't recommend using one of the smart pointers for what you are doing.

**Edit after update**

Since you already have an `Image` class that hides the buffer from you, `std::vector<uint8_t>` of course does not make any sense. In that case really one of the smart pointers would be your best choice. Which one you take depends on the following:

If you have functions that take a `std::shared_ptr<Image>` it would make sense to store your `Image` as `std::shared_ptr<Image>`.

If you have functions that take a `Image*` or `Image const*` you can still go with `std::shared<Image>` but `std::unique_ptr<Image>` would also work, since you can get a raw pointer to the object by calling `std::unique_ptr::get()`.
So using `std::unique_ptr` does not prevent you from passing your `Image` around. You just have to make sure that the object isn't deallocated while there are still references to it. That shouldn't be a problem, since you are storing it inside your main app class.

Comment: That last paragraph makes no sense. You're comparing apples to oranges. What's wrong with a `unique_ptr` to a vector if the occasion demands it?

Comment: I clarified what I was trying to say. There is nothing wrong with smart pointers, I love them ;)

Comment: So you would say its ok to use container formats even when there is only one object at the same time? I have the (maybe wrong) thought, that this is not very efficient (also, because one has to use the unnecessary container interface in the simple case).

Comment: @Meiner What do you mean with *use container formats even when there is only one object*? The only thing that is "not efficient" regarding standard containers is that they are dynamically allocated, but if you don't want to be limited to some statically defined limit you would have to do that yourself anyway (and in that case the vector will most likely be faster than your self-coded version).

Comment: Better now except it still makes no sense. Storing the size of the buffer and simple resizing is _entirely_ nothing to do with what `unique_ptr` gives you.

Comment: @Meiner: _"that this is not very efficient"_ eh? One object? What?

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit: What I mean is: When I know that there will be only one dynamically loaded object in the program at the same time (lets say an image file), my first thought was: Why should I use containers when I don't need their interfaces in my program. I do not construct container formats by myself, I have a class Image which hides the loading of the file with a correspoding image loading library. And my question is how to store this kind of object: non-pointer member, pointer (unique,shared) and so on.

Comment: What does your image loading library return?